# Search index of one Dimensional array in two dimensional array and return row by row java

Tags: java, arrays, search, multidimensional-array, bigdata

I've got a problem is that I have an array one dimensional

```
String[] purposeAll= {"P1","P2"};
```

and array two dimension

```
String[][] purpose = { 
        { "P1", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "h" },
        { "P2", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "g", "i" },
        { "P3", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q" } };
```

I need to search each index of array one dimension in array two dimension and result will get:

```
arrayOfPurpose[][]={ 
        { "P1", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "h" },
        { "P2", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "g", "i" }  };
```

and my code is

```
public static void ArrayOfPurpose(String[][] purpose, String[] purposeAll) {

String[][][] arrayOfPurpose = new String[purposeAll.length][purpose.length][];
    ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    for (int i = 0; i < purpose.length; i++) {
        list.add(purpose[i]);
    }
    String[] tmp;
    for (int k = 0; k < purposeAll.length; k++) {
        arrayOfPurpose[k]= new String[purposeAll.length][];
        System.out.print("ok");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            tmp = list.get(i);
            arrayOfPurpose[i]= new String[purposeAll.length][tmp.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < purpose[i].length; j++) {
                 if (tmp[0] == (purposeAll[k])) {
                    arrayOfPurpose[k][i][j] = tmp[j];
                  System.out.println(arrayOfPurpose[k][i][j]);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

thank you very much !! :)

Comment: Just to be clear... you want to take each value from `purposeAll[]` and check if it's value is the first one in the 2D array list of values. if so, pull it out and place the whole String[] into `arrayOfPurpose`?

Comment: Why is arrayOfPurpose 3d in your code?

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard - It's not 3D

Comment: What's the question? What's the problem with the code you have so far?

Comment: yes, in fact, i want in two dimensional array but i can't do that why i write in 3 dimension but it work error when loop turn to k=1 on so on....

Comment: @Ascalonian `String[][][] arrayOfPurpose = new String[purposeAll.length][purpose.length][];`

Comment: i want the result in two dimension array !!!

Comment: Ah, good catch! I didn't go that far into the code haha. Just was going by the definitions above

Comment: @DaraTith - Are you allowed to use ArrayList in the code? Or just matters that he return is String[ ][ ]?

Comment: i want to return String[][].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood the issue correctly.

```
    String[] purposeAll= {"P1","P2"};
    //String[] purposeAll= {"P3","P1"}; Testing Stuff.

    String[][] purpose = { 
    { "P1", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "h" },
    { "P2", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "g", "i" },
    { "P3", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q" } };

    List<String[]> arrayOfPurposes = new ArrayList<>();
    //Looping through the purposeAll to check purpose's first 
    //entry and seeing if it equals the first purposeAll value
    for(int i = 0; i < purpose.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < purposeAll.length; j++){
            if(purpose[i][0].equals(purposeAll[j])){
                arrayOfPurposes.add(purpose[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    //One way to get the results into a String[][]
    String[][] result = {arrayOfPurposes.get(0),arrayOfPurposes.get(1)};

    //Displaying to console
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(result[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I feel though you should use a List of String[] instead of String[][] because of the initialization of result being so straightforward. Also lists in most instances are more efficient and helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Using what you have in your question, in a non-Java8 way, you can do this:

```
for (String valueToCheck : purposeAll) {
    for (String[] values : purpose) {
        if (values[0].equals(valueToCheck)) {
            list.add(values);
        }
    }
}

String[][] arrayOfPurpose = new String[list.size()][];

int index = 0;

for (String[] a : list) {
    arrayOfPurpose[index++] = a;
}


System.out.println("Size of arrayOfPurpose: " + arrayOfPurpose.length);
```

Comment: No Arrays.asList().contains()?

Comment: buddy, it's nearly similar to mind but the problem i face is can't insert to array[][]. :(

Comment: @DaraTith - Look at the new comments. I got it working using that logic :-)

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard - There are many ways to check. Since the OP seems to be learning on this, figured I would give a more straight forward example

Answer (score 1):

Java8 streams solution:

```
public class blah {

    static String[] purposeAll= {"P1","P2"};

    static String[][] purpose = { 
            { "P1", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "h" },
            { "P2", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "g", "i" },
            { "P3", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q" } };
    public static String[][] arrayOfPurpose(String[][] purpose, String[] purposeAll) {
        return Arrays.asList(purpose).stream()
            .filter(arr -> Arrays.asList(purposeAll).contains(arr[0]))
            .toArray(String[][]::new);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayOfPurpose(purpose, purposeAll)));
        // prints [[P1, a, b, c, d, e, f, h], [P2, a, b, c, d, e, g, i]]
    }
}
```

Comment: i got result: P3lmnopq but not P1 and P2.